# Does OpenShift Online provide an API to manage apps?

Tags: openshift

Can't see from the doc whether I can launch / manage apps on OpenShift Online, via a standard Java API ([like Cloudbees has](https://github.com/cloudbees/cloudbees-api-client))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, More informations at [Rest API Tutorial](https://www.openshift.com/developers/rest-api-tutorial) and the full doc at [Openshift REST API PDF](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/pdf/REST_API_Guide/OpenShift_Online-2.0-REST_API_Guide-en-US.pdf)